# Implementing push notification without a third party

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification

I'm building a web social app, much like facebook, and have been looking on adding psuh notifications that will be presented on my site. I have no interest in android apps notifications or in desktop notifications (not right now at least).

I know some things are easier done using a third party, but I've been looking for examples using pure PHP and JS. Comet technique or otherwise.

So far I haven't find one examples that implements push notifications from scratch, at least not something written in the last 10 years.

Is there any modern approach to this without using Google, Ape or other vendor?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find out an answer to this question?

Comment: Yes, I found a comet-based solution as well as a more modern approach. I can post an answer after I implement it in my project. If you need a solution now let me more and I'll provide some links.

Comment: Oh nice! Does it still show notifications even if the tab isn't open like normal push notifications would?

Comment: Umm well mine would because it's a chrome extension but I'm not sure about normal client.

Comment: Ah I see - I was hoping you had a way of working it with just the normal push notifications and a servie worker

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    if (!Notification) {
      alert('Notification not supported');
      return;
    }
  });
  if (Notification.permission !== "granted"){
      Notification.requestPermission();}
  function notif(bodis) {
    if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
      Notification.requestPermission();
    else {
      var notification = new Notification('Macantameal', {
        icon: 'url/to/icon.png',
        body: bodis,
      });

      notification.onclick = function () {
        window.open("window/open/on/notification/click");      
      };
    }
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="notif('halo dunia');">NOTIFY ME</button>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.